# Burninate [adobe] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

To support burninating movement I suggest to eliminate the [adobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe) tag. There are tags for each of the products of Adobe (flash, air, flex*) and their language (actionscript*, ).

Comment: burMinate?  Trogdor is most unhappy with this.

Comment: @Powerlord I don't know what you are talking about. *whistle*