# Clean up [adobe-xxx] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Most of Adobe's graphic applications are scriptable, and with shared languages; but since they all have a DOM of their own, it seems logical to have separate tags for Illustrator, Photoshop, and InDesign.

But there seems to be some inconsistency in this:

1. Illustrator has a tag [adobe-illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator); probably because the simple tag [illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/illustrator) would seem to invite people to use this as a *job* description instead;
2. Photoshop has [photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) -- a proper name so famous, it has been added as a verb in [dictionaries](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/photoshop);
3. InDesign has [adobe-indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) (approx. 400 questions) and [indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indesign) (approx. 150 questions) -- *both* are used in approx. 100 questions.

Obviously, the two InDesign tags can be merged. But as what -- [indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indesign) (as this is unique enough to identify it) or [adobe-indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign), per Illustrator sample?

Would adding [adobe-photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) be a good move? Would *removing* "Adobe" from [adobe-illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) be useful?

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253931/burninate-adobe-tag

Comment: [meta-tag:status-partially-completed], I've synonymized [indesign] and [adobe-indesign]. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271594/merge-the-adobe-indesign-and-indesign-tag