# Merge [adobe-indesign] and [indesign]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

they're synonyms. I'm guessing the [indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indesign) tag should be removed as [adobe-indesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) is more precise.

Comment: @jongware - are you the jongware from the adobe forums? anyway no answers/decisions exist for that question

Comment: Yeah -- I cannot decide what best fits SO guidelines and I was hoping for someone with authority to decide either way :( Instead of deleting, perhaps each one in my set could be made an alias of the other. (Also, yes I am.)

Comment: i vote to keep adobe-* because a future open source project could be started with the same name. Also, it's in keeping with other stackexchange sites

Comment: "InDesign" is a trademark of Adobe, Inc., so it's actually unlikely open source projects (or any others!) could legally be named so. Neither [tag:windows] nor [tag:visual-studio] bear a "Microsoft" prefix. Then again, these two are 'famous' and unique; contrast [tag:google-maps], where `maps` in itself would be not. But ... *again* again, according to this, "Chrome" in [tag:google-chrome] should suffice! [tag:adobe] in itself seems superfluous.

Comment: but there are lots of additional adobe products which are lesser known and less brandable such as bridge, prelude, audition etc which may have duplicate projects already out there. Either way, A decision needs to be made

Comment: This should be re-opened - "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". It doesn't have an answer!

Comment: Had to do this in the reverse way, sorry for that. [tag:indesign] had 2.5 times more posts than [tag:adobe-indesign], Hence the system chose [tag:indesign] as the master.

Comment: @BhargavRao can the synonym be reverted (making [tag:adobe-indesign] a main tag)? People still asking questions using combination of [tag:adobe] + [tag:indesign] tags.

Comment: done, @VadimKotov